# SetTimer vs CWnd::SetTimer

Tags: winapi, mfc

#### Background

MFC's `CWnd::SetTimer` calls WinAPI's `SetTimer` simply.

```
_AFXWIN_INLINE UINT_PTR CWnd::SetTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent, UINT nElapse,
        void (CALLBACK* lpfnTimer)(HWND, UINT, UINT_PTR, DWORD))
    { ASSERT(::IsWindow(m_hWnd)); return ::SetTimer(m_hWnd, nIDEvent, nElapse,
        lpfnTimer); }
```

But [SetTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906(v=vs.85).aspx) and [CWnd::SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#settimer) documents are not same.

#### 1. `nIDEvent` parameter

> `SetTimer`:
>   If the *hWnd* parameter is not **NULL** and the window specified by *hWnd* already has a timer with the value *nIDEvent*, then the existing timer is replaced by the new timer. When **SetTimer** replaces a timer, the timer is reset.
>
> `CWnd::SetTimer`:
>   Specifies a nonzero timer identifier. If the timer identifier is unique, this same value is returned by `SetTimer`. Otherwise, `SetTimer` determines a new unique value and returns that. For a window timer (which has a NULL callback function), the value must be unique only for other windows timers that are associated with the current window. For a callback timer, the value must be unique for all timers in all processes. Therefore, when you create a callback timer, it is more likely that the returned value might differ from the value you specify.

`SetTimer` does not depend on callback parameter and always replaces the existing timer. But `CWnd::SetTimer` depends on callback parameter, and if callback specified, a new timer ID may be generated because **the value must be unique for all timers in all processes**.

#### 2. Return value

> `SetTimer`:
>   If the function succeeds and the *hWnd* parameter is not **NULL**, then the return value is a nonzero integer. An application can pass the value of the *nIDEvent* parameter to the **KillTimer** function to destroy the timer.
>
> `CWnd::SetTimer`:
>   The timer identifier of the new timer if the function is successful. This value may or may not be equal to the value passed in through the `nIDEvent` parameter. An application should always pass the return value to the KillTimer member function to kill the timer.

`SetTimer` does not generate new timer id and does not return timer id, so call `KillTimer` with `nIDEvent` parameter. But `CWnd::SetTimer` generates new timer id in some case, so call `KillTimer` with the returned value.

Thus, which document is correct?

---

I want to use WinAPI `SetTimer` with a callback and it works on my pc. But if some platform does not replace the existing timer, I could not accept the callback timer.

Comment: I rely on the documented behaviour of `SetTimer()` and it seems to work as advertised.  If you really want to know, you should run some simple tests.

Comment: When there is a difference between MFC and WinAPI documentation, I usually rely on the latter. After all it is the primary source of information.

Comment: Especially in cases like this where MFC simply forwards to the API. For all I know the MFC docs were correct when written but the API changed and MFC never updated to match.

Comment: Does MFC date back to 16-bit Windows? The limitation on "all processes" doesn't make much sense in a modern world.

Comment: @MarkRansom, yes: MFC was introduced in 1992 with Microsoft's C/C++ 7.0 compiler for use with 16-bit versions of Windows as an extremely thin object-oriented C++ wrapper for the Windows API (Wikipedia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MFC documentation is incorrect, as far as I can tell.  I have tested extensively, and the timers always replace the previous timer, provided the window is the same.  This is true with callbacks and without.

With a callback, I ran the following test:

```
static void CALLBACK MyTimerProc(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, UINT_PTR nIDEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
    KillTimer(hWnd, nIDEvent);
}
...
timerID = SetTimer(2, 1000, MyTimerProc);
timerID = SetTimer(2, 1100, MyTimerProc);
timerID = SetTimer(4, 1200, MyTimerProc);
timerID = GetParentFrame()->SetTimer(4, 1300, MyTimerProc);
```

Results were (from VS debugger trace):

```
timerID=2
timerID=2
timerID=4
timerID=4
nIDEvent=2, hWnd=0x00000000002d0bb8
nIDEvent=4, hWnd=0x00000000002d0bb8
nIDEvent=4, hWnd=0x0000000000140bd0
```

The last SetTimer call used a different window, which gave the same event twice.  But every time, the return value is identical to the value passed for the timer.  And the same value is used for nIDEvent.

The CWnd documentation is either out of date, or acting out of extreme caution--we know the return value is the ID, so we should always use that.

However, one statement is clearly false:

<s>For a callback timer, the value must be unique for all timers in all processes</s>

I just demonstrated I could use the same ID twice, within the *same* process, and still receive both events.