# OnTimer is getting called only once

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, mfc, dialog

I have a simple MFC **Dialog-based** Application. I subclass `CListCtrl` and handle messages in my own class. In that class, I call `SetTimer(0,15000,NULL)` to display message box for testing purpose . The problem is, it displays only one time and not getting called later.

**In main dialog**

```
DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_LIST1, m_listView);
```

**In `CListCtrl` subclassed**

```
SetTimer(0,15000,NULL);
```

**In `OnTimer()`**

```
void CMyListView::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default
    if (nIDEvent == 0)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Timer"));
    }

    CListCtrl::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: I have tried another event ID and got the same result

Comment: Can you explain, why you are passing 0 as the `nIDEvent` argument?

Comment: Where exactly do you call `SetTimer(0,15000,NULL);`? It should be in `OnInitDialog`. Read closely the documentation of `SetTimer` especially the values the first argument can take.

Comment: Re: `The problem is, it displays only one time and not getting called later.` - do you close that message box or let it hang?

Comment: Did your read the `SetTimer()` function documentation (in both the `Win32 API` and the `CWnd` class)? Why a zero timer identifier? Use a nonzero value, and make sure `SetTimer()` is called only once (eg play a sound, like `Beep(800,500)` immediately after calling `SetTimer()`). Calling `SetTimer()` again with the same timer ID will replace the previous timer with a new one and will return the new ID. Also check its return value. Take a look here: [SetTimer vs CWnd::SetTimer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010727/settimer-vs-cwndsettimer).

Comment: Why are you calling `CListCtrl::OnTimer(nIDEvent);` instead of `CYourListCtrlSubClass::OnTimer(nIDEvent);` ?!